# JAR error when using JNLP

Tags: java, build, jar

I am learning JavaWebStart service. I am following this  [**Tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/) This is my directory structure. When doing 4th step, I am getting  **jar is not recognized as an internal or external command** I executed the command in the TestJnlp.java file location. Do I need anything to run this? I have jre and jdk installed in my system.
[image: DIRECTORY structure.]

Answer (score 2):

Just add the path to system variable. These are the steps:

```
Right click on MyComputer-->
Properties-->Advanced System Settings(Windows7)-->
Environment Variables-->System Variables-->
Search for PATH in the list-->Click on edit-->
 Give a semi colon if not present--> Copy and paste the path to "\jdk1.7.0\bin"
```

Now, open a new command prompt and then use jar.